# GeoServer: colormap for point data

Tags: geoserver, point, color-ramp, colormap

How could I create a continuous colormap for point data in GeoServer?
I am planning to serve satellite measurements (METOP IASI) as point data in GeoServer 2.15 and want the point colors to represent the measured values. I initially thought I could easily define an SLD style with a colormap, like I did before for raster data, but it seems colormap styling is not available for point vector data. I could assign colors to value bins, but that would give a discrete color map rather than a continuous one. Any ideas?

Comment: wouldn't satellite measurements be better represented as a raster anyway?

Comment: Maybe you are right, Ian; the Geo world is rather new to me. Most of my satellite data is swath data. I have made a few attempts to rasterize it, but quickly ran into memory problems when rasterizing the whole world at, e.g. 0.05 degree resolution. Since the IASI instrument has a circular (well, actually elliptical) field of view I thought of the point data approach